# Google Maps API fails Geolocation on Android using Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, google-maps, cordova

I am building an application using Phonegap and Google Maps API but i found an issue that i can't fix: if i test the app on a laptop browser (chrome and firefox tested) the app works totally fine! Otherwise **when i build the app for my smartphone (OnePlus One) the map didn't show** and always the method calls the fail function.

This happens with my custom code and with the example function founded on the google api and jquery mobile site.

Here the tutorial code that works on browser and not on device

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#map-page", function() {
var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0983425, -118.3267434);  // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support
if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
    function success(pos) {
        // Location found, show map with these coordinates
        drawMap(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
    }
    function fail(error) {
        drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // Failed to find location, show default map
    }
    // Find the users current position.  Cache the location for 5 minutes, timeout after 6 seconds
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});
} else {
    drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // No geolocation support, show default map
}
function drawMap(latlng) {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
    // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: "Greetings!"
    });
}
});
```

It always starts the fail function.

I really don't understand why works on browser and not on device.

**EDIT**

Added Android Manifest

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000"       android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.coolappz.TrovaOfficine" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission           android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

**LAST UPDATE**

The problem has been fixed by himself :D
I mean: i uninstalled the app from device, rebooted the phone, deleted unused plugins from the project and then on the new build and installation everything worked fine. 
I guess it was a plugin issue.

Comment: Have you installed the geolocation plugin? `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation` See: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on the geolocation on your phone? Like GPS or something?

Because I had similar experience, and it was because my Nexus 7 doesn't have GPS.. Kinda silly in my part..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes i checked it and tryed with geolocation ON and OFF too but still not working

Comment: Umm can you post your manifest? Did you give the permission for the app ?

Comment: Try moving all your `<uses-permission />` tag to above your `<application />` tag :D

Comment: If the map can be displayed in Browser, but not Smartphone, that should mean that the geolocation function fails in the Smartphone.. Sorry that I couldn't help much but I can only suggest that try checking the geolocation function. Try using apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sanmeetk.GPSTestSuite&hl=en to check whether your GPS is okay I guess.. I'm going to sleep for now and hope that by tomorrow you'll find the answer! I'm still curious though, so I'll also find the answer  myself :D